# Relationship between centralization and floating-point arithmetic

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose I have a problem of least squares where I have $n$ independents regressor variables $x_i$, and suppose I applied the process of centralization and scaling to this variable through
$$z_i=\frac{x_i-\bar{X}}{\sigma}$$
where $\bar{T}=\frac{\sum x_i}{n}$ and $\sigma=\sqrt{\frac{(x_i-\bar{X})^2}{n}}$

I know that this procedure generally reduces the condition number of the matrix of a linear system, but I do not know what the relationship of this procedure with the floating-point arithmetic, can someone explain this to me?

EDIT: Suppose the matrix is $nxn$

Comment: Are you considering just one "regressor" variable (independent variable) $x$, or do you have multiple independent variables? I.e., what is the dimension of your design matrix for the regression problem? And on a related note, how many observations do you have relative to the number of independent variables?

Comment: @user2566092 I added some information

Comment: Condition number of a matrix affects both numerical stability of solving the linear system (e.g. if matrix has a condition number of $10^6$ you would loose 6 digits of precision from your answer) and in case if you're solving your system with an iterational method, condition number affects the number of required iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Centralization is, at least as far as I know, not really as important as normalization for some inverse problems. Note that $A^{-1} = (DA)^{-1}D$ for diagonal $D$ which, depending on how you compute an inverse, may affect the stability of the computation if the columns of $DA$ are much more on the same scale compared to the columns of $A$, due to the adjoint formula for the inverse. I suppose centralization may also play a role if some columns of normalized $A$ have large a much larger magnitude of mean than the standard deviation of the corresponding column of centralized and normalized $A$.

Comment: But what is the relationship between floating-point arithmetic and this procedure?